# Where in Sichuan is 虾 pronunced ha1 (xa⁵⁵)?

Tags: pronunciation

《现代汉语方言音库 • 成都话音档》has two listings for 虾 one that says:

> xa⁵⁵ 又ɕia⁵⁵

`xa⁵⁵` can pretty much be pinyinized as `ha1` - for simplification here.

And there is of course a second entry that says:

> ɕia⁵⁵ 又xa⁵⁵

Now of course it looks like I've answered my own question - seeing as the name of the book is **成都话**音档. But, `ha1` is not a pronunciation I've heard before for 虾 in Sichuanese and most people don't believe that it even exists. I'm curious as to where this pronunciation is still maintained in Sichuan.

It's certainly part of the vestiges of 湖广填川.

Comment: Is this an influence of e.g.「下」having two pronunciations (**ha4** / **xia4**)? Or maybe it's the way「蝦」in「蝦蟆」is pronounced?

Comment: More likely to be from Cantonese, I think.

Comment: 在我所在的湖南方言区，虾、下都发ha，夏、瑕之类发xia

Comment: 湘语 is a possibility too.

Comment: A typo here: did you mean "湖广滇川"? /// This pronunciation also exists in other places. I myself would say “等下子” [wait a minute] as in "den ha zi" [tone omitted since I do not know how to indicate them occurred in dialects] in dialect, where in Putonghua “下” is actually "xià". Also other people would say hāzi to indicate 虾子 in my hometown [I myself do not use that]. I think this pronunciation would be frequently encountered in the district of dialect that lie in the south of the Changjiang River. Maybe they have similar origins.

Comment: @xbh No typo. Sichuanese has a lot of influence from Cantonese, Hakka & Xiang, thanks to 湖广填川. Where is your hometown that 虾子 is pronounced hāzi?

Comment: @user3306356 Sorry that i commented something stupid like that without any search in advance. I was talking about Anhui, but I cannot guarantee that phenomenon appears in the whole province, since the dialect seems vary a lot here.

Answer (score 1):

It does not exist any more in Chengdu dialect (my mother's tongue), but I think if you regard Chongqing dialect as a part of Sichuanese, there must be somewhere.

The only usage of 'ha' in Chengdu dialect is in 蛤蟆 but it is ha2, and it does not seem to be a native word in Sichuanese but imported from Standard Chinese. We traditionally use 赖克宝 instead.

The dialects in some place in Chongqing sometimes pronounce 解决 as gai3 jio2. And I believe that this is because they mostly keep the original dialect inherited from Hubei/Hunan dialect. So 虾 must be pronounced as ha1 there.

Comment: Your point about “toad” could be correct, as it is sometimes written 虾蟆.